# Hot reload when login using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, authentication, rerender, hot-reload

I am login in using vuejs in Laravel, when I pushed from login to dashboard, my sidebar widgets are not working, when I hot reload them by F5 then it works. I find many solutions how to rerender the dom in vuejs
I follow this approach but still sidebar widgets are not working

```
export default {
    data:function(){
        return{
             componentKey: 0,
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        forceRerender() {
      this.componentKey += 1;
    }
    }
}
```

Sidebar.vue

```
 <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="" class="brand-link">
      <img src="images/admin/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Administrator</span>
    </a>

   
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="images/admin/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="" class="d-block">Hadi Niazi</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open">
            <a href="" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <p>
                Dashboard

              </p>
            </a>

          </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="pages/widgets.html" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
              <p>
                Widgets
                <span class="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
              <p>
                Student Record
                <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                <span class="badge badge-info right">6</span>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{ name: 'UploadStudentList' }">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Upload List</p>
                </router-link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

Sidebar code is added, please have a look on it.

Comment: Could you share the sidebar widgets code

Comment: Sure, the sidebar is working fine, I updated the post with the sidebar please have a look at it.

Comment: Okay, now what do you mean by "my sidebar widgets are not working"? It doesn't render after login? If that's the case, where is the condition to show it or not? I couldn't find it, it may be at some Sideber.vue parent?

Comment: The sidebar is rendering but when I click on the sidebar links their inner navigation links are not opening.

Comment: Hummm, and no console.errors?

Comment: Yes no console error.

Comment: Place a 'console.log(this.$router)' at mounted() hook and check if your routes are available at '.options.routes'

Comment: @Arthur Borba routes are properly working, navigation links are not opening, when I click on the nav link their inner link is not opening.

Comment: What a pickle! Maybe with a codepen I could try helping you a bit more...I have a similar code at a project and it works just fine. Or we could just wait to someone else give us this light